# How can I output attribute which type is face？

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes

I want to use a face type attribute (I made in geometry nodes and named it materialtime) in shader nodes.
But geometry nodes  return a point type attribute.
[image][image]What can I do？

Answer (score 5):

Go to the right hand side panel in the Geometry Nodes editor or press <kbd>N</kbd> to open it, open the *Group* subpanel, select your *Attribute* output in the list of outputs and change the *Attribute Domain* to *Face*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you！But I can't use  my attribute in shader node by an attribute node.Is there something todo？

Comment: What version are you using ?

Comment: I use blender ver3.1